# Spring MVC controller reached but I still get 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I have a pretty basic spring mvc web app set up, and this is the begining/section in question from my controller class

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    AssetDAO assetDAO;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
    System.out.println("HERE!");
    return "index";
}
```

and my index.jsp file

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" paegeEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "~//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org.TR.html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title> Welcome Page </title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <h1> Asset Tracking Web App Test </h1>
        <a href="EmployeeList">Get Employee Records</a>
    </div>
</body>


</html>
```

but when I access `localhost:8080/` I get a `404` error. however the message  `HERE` gets printed

EDIT: I added an application.properties file to my src/main/resources folder which fixed the issue... My question now is, how is this different from using an InternalViewResolver?? or is my understanding of this just wrong??

EDIT2: the file structure of the project is as follows

```
.
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   └── main
│       ├── java
│       │   └── com
│       │       └── assetTracking
│       │           ├── App.java
│       │           ├── AssetDAO.java
│       │           ├── Employee.java
│       │           └── MainController.java
│       ├── resources
│       │   └── application.properties
│       └── webapp
│           └── WEB-INF
│               ├── jsp
│               │   ├── employeeList.jsp
│               │   └── index.jsp
│               └── views.xml
├── tableCreatiosn.sql
├── tableEntries
```

leaving out all the dependency directories for brevity. Having the files sugggested by yates did not solve the problem. replacing them with application.properties does however

```
application.properties
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp

welcome.message: Hello Test
```

Comment: Can you modify `@RequestMapping("/")` to `@RequestMapping("/home")` and try with url `localhost:8080/home` and Paste the result.

Comment: modify  <a href="EmployeeList">Get Employee Records</a> to  <a href="/">Get Employee Records</a>

Comment: Check my answer below!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the jsp page not able to be rendered.

Try adding the following dependencies in your pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

You may need to change the jasper scope to "default" if you are running using Intellij IDE.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you haven't configured [InternalViewResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/InternalResourceViewResolver.html). If yes then it's locating `index.jsp` at some incorrect location.

Following is the configuration for `InternalViewResolver`

**XML:**

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

**Java**

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("<package_fully_qualified_name>")
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
      InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
      bean.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
      bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
      bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
      return bean;
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, with no avail, maybe I still have it configured wrong?

Comment: @justinbenge Update what you already have + the structure as well where your index.jsp recides

Comment: thank you, but I do know what to do when someone answers my question. However I used a different solution as it seemed simpler. I did ask another question though in my edit, that hasn't been answered yet

Comment: How did a property-file solve your problem?? Would like to see the code ?? Asking questions without showing what you are trying isn't a great idea

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a viewResolver bean with the properties prefix and suffix on your servlet, spring doesn't know what the suffix of "index" is, so it can't find it. You can use a viewResolver to all your jsp files.

Here is the XML configuration:

```
<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsps/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>
```

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**

To configure the servlet add this to web.xml (In your case maybe is views.xml?):

```
 <servlet>
   <servlet-name>servletname</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>servletname</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

And don't forget to create the servlet "servletname-servlet.xml", instead of servlet name you can out the name of your app. Then add the bean above to your servlet and it should work.

Check [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_web_mvc_framework.htm), it may help you in case I forgot anything else.

Comment: I can't comment on your question, so I'll do it here. As I said above, your ViewResolver has to be on your servlet. In your edit I can't see a servlet, usually it's located in WEB-INF, like your views.xml. You could call it  "yourappname-servlet.xml".  Give it a try